# Pandas multiindex dataframe get top 5 row of each sorted group

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a multiindex DataFrame like following:

[image]

I want to sort each poster group (descending) and get the top-5. If the number of poster less than 5, drop the record.

Comment: First, please include a sample of your data frame in your question instead of posting a link. Then, post what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]:
               Time
waller poster
1      11         2
       22         3
       33         1
       44         1
       55         1
2      33         1
3      11         1
       22         1
       33         1
       44         2
       55         1
       66         3
```

**Solution:**

```
In [98]: (df.sort_index(ascending=[1,0])
    ...:    .groupby(level=0, as_index=False)
    ...:    .apply(lambda x: x.head(5) if len(x) >= 5 else x.head(0))
    ...:    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[98]:
               Time
waller poster
1      55         1
       44         1
       33         1
       22         3
       11         2
3      66         3
       55         1
       44         2
       33         1
       22         1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
g = df.groupby(level=0)

def lrgst(df):
    if len(df) >= 5:
        return df.nlargest(5, 'Time')

pd.concat([lrgst(d) for _, d in g])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To sort the poster column you can use [sort level](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html)

```
df.sortlevel(1, ascending=False)
```

To get the top n results you can use [.head](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)

```
df.head(5)
```

To drop records you can reference the respective level:

```
df = df[df.index.levels[1] > 5]
```

Let me know if this helps. Its hard to say if this will answer your problem with the limited information